# Showing that $\mathrm{Var}(Y) \leq \mathrm{Var}(X)$

Tags: probability, expected-value, variance

> Let $X$ be a random variable with $\mathbb{E}(X^2) <\infty$. Let $Y$ defined as 
>   $$Y=\begin{cases}X &\text{ if }& \mid X\mid\leq k \\
> 0 &\text{ if }& \mid X\mid > k
> \end{cases}$$
>   Show that $\mathrm{Var}(Y) \leq \mathrm{Var}(X)$.

I tried solving it this way:

\begin{align}\mathrm{Var(Y)}&=\int (Y-\mathbb{E}(Y))^2d\mathrm{P}=\int_{\mid x \mid \leq k} (Y-\mathbb{E}(Y))^2d\mathrm{P} +\int_{\mid x \mid > k} (Y-\mathbb{E}(Y))^2d\mathrm{P}\\
&=\mathbb{E}(Y^2)P(({\mid x \mid \leq k})\cup ({\mid x \mid > k}))\\
& \leq \mathbb{E}(Y)^2+\mathbb{E}(X^2)\\
&=\mathbb{E}(X^2)-\mathbb{E}(Y)^2\\
&\leq \mathrm{Var}(X)\end{align}

Is this correct?

Comment: k is fixed? also, what have you tried?

Comment: The last two steps in you argument make no sense

Comment: Where does the exercise come from ?

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure the statement is true.

Take a discrete variable $X$ such that:

- $X=0.8$ with probability $0.5$ and $X=1.0$ with probability $0.5$.

We have $E[X]=0.9$, $E[X^2]=0.82$ and $Var(X)=0.01$.

Now take $k=0.9$. Than:

- $Y=0.8$ with probability $0.5$ and $Y=0$ with probability $0.5$.

This leads to $E[Y]=0.4$, $E[Y^2]=0.32$ and $Var(Y)=0.16$.

So the variance has in this case incremented: $Var(Y) \ge Var(X)$. Is the counterexample correct ?

Comment: Yes, the counterexample is correct! Thus, the statement in the OP is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Try to do it using definiton : $$\mathbb{Var}(X) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} (X-\operatorname{E}X)^2 \mu(dx) \le \int_{{[-k,k]}}(X - \operatorname{E}X)^2 = \dots$$

Comment: The inequality is in the wrong direction and I have no idea how this leads to a complete answer. Could you please write a more detailed proof?